# Is there a import class shortcut/feature in Cloud9 as there is in Eclipse?

Tags: cloud9-ide, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I am experimenting with [Cloud 9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/)

This is my current code(In Vehicle.java)

```
public abstract class Vehicle{
    List<String> tags;
}
```

Eclipse has this shortcut where you can scroll over a class you haven't imported(in this case List) and the IDE will make suggestions on where to import the class.

I'am looking for similar functionality in Cloud9 as I believe this will be major time saver in in the future.

I've looked through the Cloud9 IDE [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/tutorial.html#tutorial-tour-ide) and saw a code autocompletion cloud9 [feature](https://docs.c9.io/docs/autocompletion).

However I wasn't able to find anything similar to the "smart" import class feature that Eclipse has. Does anyone know if this feature is available in Cloud9 as of this moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you tagged your post with aws-cloud9. As of the date of this response, AWS Cloud9 does not support code hints for Java. For updated information about AWS Cloud9 support for various programming languages, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/language-support.html

Paul (AWS Cloud9 Documentation)

Comment: You don't need to put a signature in every one of your posts. See: [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)